# Why is sum() used when the percentage is computed?

Tags: pandas

```
df[percent] = (df['column_name'] / df['column_name'].sum()) * 100
```

My dataset is:

| name_d | year | regime_origin | FLOW | GDP_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITALY | 1990 | 0 | 120 | 200 |
| ITALY | 1991 | 0 | 239 | 500 |
| SPAIN | 1990 | 1 | 123 | 399 |
| ITALY | 1993 | 1 | 120 | 200 |

I would like to have the percentage of the FLOW.

I would have:

```
df[percent] = (df['FLOW'] / df['GDP_d']) * 100
```

But some source says I have to use .sum(). Why is sum() necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to compute the percentage that each value from the column `FLOW` has **relative to the total flow**, then you really need to divide each value by the sum of all values:

```py
df[percent] = (df['column_name']/df['column_name'].sum()) * 100
```

When you have something like:

```py
df[percent] = (df['FLOW'] / df['GDP_d']) * 100
```

What you're actually calculating is the value that the `FLOW` of each row has, relative to that same row's `GDP_d`. So for example, on the first line, a flow of 120 represents 60% of the `GDP_d` (200). The second line equals 47.80%, and so on. If `FLOW` and `GDP_d` columns are relatable in a sense that `GDP_d` represents the maximum that every element from `FLOW` could have then it's completely fine to use `(df['FLOW'] / df['GDP_d']) * 100`.

However if in reality you wanted to find the average percentage of each `FLOW` observation (observation = row), in respect to its total population (all values of `FLOW` combined), then you really need to divide each value by the sum of all values.

It's important to note that the sum of all values you get when you divide `FLOW` by `GDP_d` won't add up to 100%. In your example, the sum would be equal to 198.62%, and the average of `df[percent]` would be 49.65%. This means that, on average, the value of each row from `FLOW` is about 50% of size of `GDP_d`.

On the other hand, when you calculate the percentage `FLOW` in respect to the total `FLOW` population the sum of all values is always equal to 100%.

Here's an comparison:

|  | name_d | year | regime_origin | FLOW | GDP_d | FLOW/GDP_d | EQUATION(FLOW/GDP_d) | FLOW/SUM(FLOW) | EQUATION(FLOW/SUM(FLOW)) | FLOW/SUM(GDP_d) | EQUATION(FLOW/SUM(GDP_d)) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ITALY | 1990 | 0 | 120 | 200 | 60 | 120/200 | 19.93 | 120/602 | 9.24 | 120/1299 |
| 1 | ITALY | 1991 | 0 | 239 | 500 | 47.8 | 239/500 | 39.7 | 239/602 | 18.4 | 239/1299 |
| 2 | SPAIN | 1990 | 1 | 123 | 399 | 30.83 | 123/399 | 20.43 | 123/602 | 9.47 | 123/1299 |
| 3 | ITALY | 1993 | 1 | 120 | 200 | 60 | 120/200 | 19.93 | 120/602 | 9.24 | 120/1299 |

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "name_d": ["ITALY", "ITALY", "SPAIN", "ITALY"],
        "year": [1990, 1991, 1990, 1993],
        "regime_origin": [0, 0, 1, 1],
        "FLOW": [120, 239, 123, 120],
        "GDP_d": [200, 500, 399, 200],
    }
)


df['FLOW/GDP_d'] = ((df['FLOW'] / df['GDP_d']) * 100).round(2)
df['EQUATION(FLOW/GDP_d)'] = df.apply(lambda row: f'{row["FLOW"]:0d}/{row["GDP_d"]:0d}', axis=1)
df['FLOW/SUM(FLOW)'] = ((df['FLOW'] / df['FLOW'].sum()) * 100).round(2)
df['EQUATION(FLOW/SUM(FLOW))'] = df.apply(lambda row: f'{row["FLOW"]:0d}/{df["FLOW"].sum():0d}', axis=1)
df['FLOW/SUM(GDP_d)'] = ((df['FLOW'] / df['GDP_d'].sum()) * 100).round(2)
df['EQUATION(FLOW/SUM(GDP_d))'] = df.apply(lambda row: f'{row["FLOW"]:0d}/{df["GDP_d"].sum():0d}', axis=1)
```

Comment: That was so helpful! Many thank!